# PyQt5 failing import of QtGui, QtCore and so on

Tags: python, pyqt, qtgui, qtcore, qtwidgets

[OS]
- Windows 7 64bit

[Version]
- Python 3.4
- PyQt5.4.1

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QtGui, QtCore
```

I cannot import ***QtGui, QtCore*** in ***QtWidgets***.
I have qtgui.pyd and qtcore.pyd, but I can't import them...
Besides, I have ***QApplication*** but it's also not imported.
Did I install Python3.4 wrongly?

if someone have an idea to fix this, please answer me.
I think there is no right answer about this problem for me yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement is incorrect for PyQt5:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
```

If you want to import `QApplication`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
```

[pyqt4_differences](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html)

Comment: But, I also couldn't import QApplication :(

Comment: I just installed the file I download on the website. Now I installed the python3.4 64bit and pyqt4 again. it works! thanks anyway :)